# Android: Rounded Corners TextView XML Layout with custom Header

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, android-drawable

I would like to create a custom XML layout for my TextView, using rounded corners and a custom header, such as this example.

[image]

I found this very [useful link](http://www.donnfelker.com/android-rounded-corners-with-a-beveldrop-shadow/) that creates the following quite similar result.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Bottom 2dp Shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#d8d8d8" />
            <corners android:radius="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- White Top color -->
    <item android:bottom="3px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="7dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I wonder if it possibile to modify the XML layout above to get the header "ADD FRIEND" style, that is the darker gray background and the divider between the header textview ("ADD FRIEND") and the textview below (the one containing the "Nickname or email" and the "search" button).

I am thinking it is probably easier to do it with an image/drawable background, but getting it done in XML would be awesome (in terms of reusability for example).

Any help or suggestion on how to proceed is very welcome!

Comment: Why not just use two TextViews and set that drawable as background to the layout?

Comment: That could be a good idea I need to try, thanks.

Comment: Have You worked it out? If so, You can share an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

if you not using image for that then require three xml in drawable and create this type of layout :
1 linearlayout_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#CABBBBBB" />

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

2. header_background :

```
<item><shape>
        <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" />

        <corners android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

        <solid android:color="@color/off_black1" />
    </shape></item>
```

3. buttonbackground

```
<item><shape>
        <padding android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" />

        <corners android:radius="5dp" />

        <solid android:color="#00000000" />

        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/off_white2" />
    </shape></item>
```