# RectF is not painted on canvas

Tags: android, paint, rect

I have a small question. I'm painting some RectFs on my canvas, but nothing happened.

I paint one filled RectF and another stroked RectF => filled background with a border. 
For the first "field" everything is ok, but not for the second "field" (rect2).

The positions are checked. The last text is printed in that RectF (rect2) where the rect is not painted.

I uploaded an image on my FTP server. For the description of my problem it might be easier to understand. 
[image]

Here is my code. I think it is a logical error?

```
// Fill rect
rect.set(fPosition, fPositionY, pts[2] - 10, fRectHeight);
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
paint.setStyle(android.graphics.Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 10, 10, paint);
// Border
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setStyle(android.graphics.Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 10, 10, paint);

// Text
float fTextSize = fRectHeight - 40;
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
textPaint.setTextSize(fTextSize);
float textHeight = textPaint.descent() - textPaint.ascent();
float textOffset = (textHeight / 2) - textPaint.descent();
canvas.drawText(dataStrings.getGewicht(), rect.centerX(), rect.centerY() + textOffset, textPaint);

// Leistung pro Stunde
rect2 = new RectF();        
paint = new android.graphics.Paint();
fPositionY = fPositionY + fRectHeight + 50;
float fRectWidth = pts[2] / 2;  
fRectHeight = (float) (pts[17] / 5);    

// Fill rect
rect2.set(fPosition, fPositionY, fRectWidth, fRectHeight);
paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
paint.setStyle(android.graphics.Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect2, 10, 10, paint);                     
// Border
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
paint.setStyle(android.graphics.Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
canvas.drawRoundRect(rect2, 10, 10, paint);

// Text
fTextSize = fRectHeight - 40;
textPaint = new TextPaint();
textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
textPaint.setTextSize(fTextSize);
textHeight = textPaint.descent() - textPaint.ascent();
textOffset = (textHeight / 2) - textPaint.descent();
canvas.drawText(dataStrings.getLeistung(), rect2.centerX(), rect2.centerY() + textOffset, textPaint);
```

Comment: Instead of highly unoptimized custom drawing code, why not use xml? E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464709/android-rounded-corners-textview-xml-layout-with-custom-header or http://android-er.blogspot.de/2013/02/define-shape-for-view-using-xml.html - I'd also suggest you use methods instead of duplicating your drawing code. It's just much simpler to find a bug if you have just 1 place of code to fix.

Comment: This image is only a part of a greater one. It's a small app to visulize a PLC.

Comment: Another argument against your approach if you ask me. Supporting different screen sizes will be fun if all code looks like this. You've hardcoded all the sizes in pixels for example. That's going to be too small on a higher res device and too big on a low res one. Sidenote: `paint.setAntiAlias(true)` to make it look smooth as the rest of android

Comment: Ok. If I would paint the image in the XML file, what are the possibilities? Would it be possible to paint containers which are connected by tubes? In the conatainers there must be texts (like in the picture above) which should be updated every X seconds. Maybe you know a good "HowTo"?

Comment: What you can do quite easily via XML is to add a styled background to `TextView` so you'll have text inside rounded rectangles. Connecting tubes between them sounds unlikely to work that way. You could maybe combine custom drawing with some XML layout but I don't know of a good way to do so, especially if tubes are more than just simple straight connections.

Comment: I have implemented a mixture of drawing things and work with background styles. The fixed sizes were changed to percental values. I think it's a good solution. It works on small phones (3.2") as well on 5.1" (Samsung S5) and on tablets (10.1") in portrait and landscape mode. Thank you very much, zapl.